# Как отправить изображение в бд, mvc

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel, mvc

Каким образом можно отправить картинку в базу данных, можно через метод пост, но ларваел выдает ошибку tokenmismatchexception, в роутах к странице прописал Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'reviews', 'ReviewsController@show'); , все равно не робит как тут быть?

Comment: форма перекидывает на ту же страницу

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего причина в CSRF, добавьте в форму поле:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Если отправляете форму через Ajax, то добавьте тег `meta`:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

И укажите ajax config:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Более подробно можете почитать в [офф. документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf)

Answer (score 1):

Если скрипт делает сериализацию данных в форме отправки запросов (), то в форме также можно прописать

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Это добавит поле с CSRF токеном в форму, как показал Yaroslav Molchan